# HTML Form Number field with plus and minus quantities

Tags: html, forms

I have a basic, one field form that only accepts numbers and defaults to zero.  A user is required to type a number in there before submitting, which is often only one or two but can be up to 1000, and I'm trying to make it more user friendly by adding a **+** and **-** box next to it so that they keyboard doesn't HAVE to be used.

**For example:** [Text Box Example http://www.performwheels.co.uk/publicsite/images/eg.jpg](http://www.performwheels.co.uk/publicsite/images/eg.jpg)

Is there an in-built feature supporting this? Or am I just going to have to write a `script` for it?

Many Thanks

**Edit:** The solution will need to be something that will allow the user to still use the page if they have an older browser,  as there will be IE7 (and possibly even earlier) users.

Comment: "possibly even... " ::shudder::

Comment: Anyway, I see your point; many browsers don't support every single HTML5 feature. For instance, Firefox 21 and IE 9 don't do type=number yet,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use HTML5 input type number. It's not supported by every browser, but the most show the little arrow buttons to change the value. Use attribute `step` to define the steps.

```
<input type='number' size='10' id='numberinput' name='mynumber' value='0' />
```

Comment: Thanks, my question is poorly asked because I was rushing - I require support for IE7, I'll get the question edited.

Comment: maybe a bit overkill, but the modernizr script should help you... https://github.com/jonstipe/number-polyfill/blob/master/number-polyfill.js

Comment: It seems that the type='number' does still work in older browsers (at least according to Chrome compatibility checker) as a normal text box.  I was under the impression it wouldn't work at all, so thanks!

Comment: type text is defined as the fallback for all unknown types. This is  also used to check in javascript whether a type is supported.

Comment: Why was the answer accepted when the edit to the question says that the purpose is to *avoid* “the HTML5 Number element”??

Comment: I think is was a missunderstanding, that JoeP thought type=input will not work at all in IE7

Comment: The question was marked as correct because it is what I've gone with.  The response was posted before I edited to include the bit about HTML5, and as I've ended up using that option it seemed fair to mark it as the correct answer.  And yes, I did also think that HTML5 elements would outright fail in earlier browsers so I've only ever used them for aesthetics rather than actual functions.

Comment: It is misleading to future readers of the question and answers that an answer that suggests a solution explicitly declared as avoidable in the (edited) question has been accepted.

Comment: Understandable, in which case I think it best that I "un-edit" my question, as without that edit the question answer is perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

Since the edit says that you do not want to use the HTML5 construct for reading a number, then the answer is that you cannot do anything in HTML beyond using a text input field. Such field will accept *any* string (possible restricted in length with the `maxlength` attribute), as far as HTML is considered.

With scripting, it is possible (and rather easy) to add buttons that increase or decrease the value in an input field. However, such user interfaces are not common, and the odds are that they will confuse the user rather than help him

Comment: Thank you, I was rather hoping the answer to be something other than "you can't", but that doesn't stop it being true!